# How to convert a multiedges graph to a none directed graph in Networkx?

Tags: networkx

I have used read_graphml to load a graph, and it looks as if it returned a Multiedges graph object, which I can't run the PageRank method on (returns an exception that the graph must be non-multiedged).
Is there a way to convert my graph to a non-multiedged type (I don't think I have multi edges in the graph I loaded...).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the read_graphml() function returned a MultiGraph() object it probably found parallel (multiple) edges in the input file.  But you can convert that to a graph without parallel edges simply by passing into a new Graph().  e.g.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.MultiGraph([(1,2),(1,2)])

In [3]: G.edges()
Out[3]: [(1, 2), (1, 2)]

In [4]: H = nx.Graph(G)

In [5]: H.edges()
Out[5]: [(1, 2)]
```

Comment: This method did not work for me. After importing into 'g' I got a 'DiGraph' instance. I tried 'nx.MultiGraph(g)' and the resulting graph had exactly half of the edges. What I would like is the same amount of edges, but for those to be undirected. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: If you get a DiGraph() instance for g then you can call pagerank(g) directly right?  If you instead get a MultiDiGraph() for g than you can call DiGraph(g) to return a graph without parallel edges.

Comment: what I want is a graph with 2 undirected edges between every pair of nodes. is that possible with any of the networkx graph types?

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to be more clear about what you are doing?  See also Graph.to_directed()